# Remove upstart option from GRUB

Tags: grub2, kernel, upstart, 15.04

For each Kernel I use with my 15.04 install I have three options in GRUB:

- normal (systemd)
- upstart
- recovery

How can I remove the `upstart` option for all my Kernels?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways you may wish to approach this one, I have tried to be complete as possible and hope that *one* of these solves your problem.

### Is it needed?

On systems up to at least 16.04, **yes**, [you need Upstart if you want to log in](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta/+bug/1582421).

But if you are completely sure that you don't need upstart at all, just uninstall it:

```
sudo apt-get purge upstart
```

that will cause it to be removed from automatically from the menu too

In the case that you NEED upstart (probably something that depends on it) and want it still around but not to start up your system, you can get rid of the entry manualling by editing your grub configuration files. There are two ways of going about it (first one being the more dangerous of the two).

### Temporary Removal

You can edit the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` for TEMPORARY removal (regenerating with grub-mkconfig will UNDO this change). Remove the menu_entry block that bears the names `Ubuntu ....... (upstart) { .. many lines .. }`.<sup>[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta/+bug/1582421)</sup>

### Preferred Removal

The annoying upstart entry is generated because of a single variable inside the `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` template file, which is what you should edit. The variable in question is called `SUPPORTED_INITS` and is set very close to the beginning of the file. If you want to get rid of support for starting upstart, you must remove it from here.

Change this:

```
SUPPORTED_INITS="sysvinit:/lib/sysvinit/init systemd:/lib/systemd/systemd upstart:/sbin/upstart"
```

To This:

```
SUPPORTED_INITS="sysvinit:/lib/sysvinit/init systemd:/lib/systemd/systemd"
```

Then you need to rebuild your boot configuration file from the template you just edited<sup>[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta/+bug/1582421)</sup>:

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

### Backup Your Changes

When making these changes, make a backup of the file you are changing, and put it in a safe place like a `~/Documents` directory or something to ensure that a package manager operation doesn't accidentally delete it. If that is too much work, just make a copy of the line you are changing, and comment it out (of course in the case of `grub.cfg`, `grub-mkconfig` would overwrite those changes the next time it was run.

---

<sup>[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta/+bug/1582421)</sup>You should always check your script after changing it to verify it will run. You can use `grub-script-check /boot/grub/grub.cfg` to ensure there are no syntax errors in your script after editing or generating a new one, and *definitely* before rebooting.

Comment: You can just run `update-grub` to rebuild the config file after changing SUPPORTED_INITS

Answer (score 2):

What about [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer)? I'm using it to cutomize Grub and never had any issue with it. Well, actually I had one once, and asked the author about it, and got a fixing answer very fast.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Could you expand this a bit, please?  How would the OP go about using Grub customizer?